# React Class Component Routing navigation

Tags: reactjs, class, components

I tried with function component useNavigate()

but I want to do samething with Class Component navigation to another component, please anyone let me know how can we do it. in coding.  I saw props.navigation.navigate() but its also not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.